How to properly call AWS bedrock using JavaScript SDK?
I am a newbie to using JavaScript SDK to connect to AWS Bedrock service, below is my code:
const { BedrockAgentRuntimeClient, RetrieveCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime");


const client = new BedrockAgentRuntimeClient({
// fake credentials
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: 'accesskey',
      secretAccessKey: 'secret',
    },
    region: "us-east-1"
});
  
const params = {
/** input parameters */
};

const command = new RetrieveCommand(params);

async function send() {
    const data = await client.send(command);

}

send();
  

In this code, what do I need to pass in params section? And, am I missing something from the code?
I searched the documentation a lot but found nothing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Never ever out valid credentials in a public forum like that. People harvest these and abuse them.

Which documentation did you read? This one? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/bedrock-agent-runtime/command/RetrieveCommand/

@SAE  No, this one: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-bedrock-agent-runtime

@SAE Also I want to chat with Bedrock agent, not the knowledgebase, because the agent has some action groups (lambda functions), that I need to be invoked.

"your" documentation leeds to the specific docs about the RetrieveCommand... So, that should answer your general question, what params expects.

@SAE the thing is,  I tried that code, and it interacts with the knowledgebase directly instead of the agent, beacuse the documentation only requires knowledgebaseId in the input, how will it know which agent i want to communicate with?

Maybe you should make your intention more clear in the question, since it's only about the params for the RetrieveCommand. I haven't worked with Bedrock, but perhaps you'll have to use the InvokeAgentCommand for dealing with the agent.
